# My Electron app gets detected as a virus by Browsers, how can I fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I made an Electron app with electron-forge, I ran `npm run make` (same as electron-forge make) and I get a perfect setup file with no problem. But when I send it to someone to download or I try to download it myself, I can't because Chrome says that It's a virus and Windows show a small warning screen that I can get past easily. How can I make the browser and Windows trust my app?

Comment: By having more people use it, or by buying and applying a digital signature.

Comment: Thanks @CherryDT is there another way to get the certificate for free or do i have to buy it

Comment: You have to buy it. Otherwise it would not be effective because every virus-creator would then also just assign a free anonymous certificate they got from somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You have to sign your application, here are the documents
https://www.electronjs.org/es/docs/latest/tutorial/code-signing
and this extra for the Windows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe