# My electron app was recognized by the windows system as a virus and directly deleted,how can i fix it

Tags: windows, powershell, electron, electron-vue

I used electron to develop a windows app, it was recognized as a virus by the windows system and deleted directly, but because the app we only use for a small number of people within the company, it's too much of a waste to do the code signing, is there any other way to make my electron app work properly and not be detected as a virus.
Below is a screenshot of my app's functionality, the only functions are login authentication and opening shared files.

1. login authentication: it is to request our company's oa authentication login interface, and it can be operated after successful authentication.
2. open shared file: it is to open the company shared folder based on inputting the account password, 3 windows commands are executed as follows:

Delete all shared links:
`net use * /delete`

Create a new link (using the OA account password):
`net use \\share.yafex.cn /user:mycompany\username password`

Open window:
`explorer.exe \\xxx.xxx.cn\share`

[Screenshot 1 of the feature request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taEiA.png)

[Screenshot 2 of the feature request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dc8K.png)

According to my need, I looked up the answer on stackoverflow website and only found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74132220/my-electron-app-gets-detected-as-a-virus-by-browsers-how-can-i-fix), but he didn't solve my problem, I hope you guys can help me to solve it! Thanks!

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the "virus" message? When exactly does the message appear? Which Windows version?

Comment: The version is Windows 10. There is no virus information, the phenomenon is like this, I sent my exe program file to my colleague's computer, my colleague's computer system directly deleted my exe program file.

Comment: You may have to whitelist the application in Windows Defender on your colleague's system.

Comment: Thanks.Just now my problem was solved, but I still don't understand the reason, I'll add what I just described, that is, my colleague's computer was sharing a folder out, I put the exe file into this shared folder, then when my colleague clicked on the install, his computer system directly deleted this exe program. Then I re-compressed this exe program file and re-uploaded it, then he extracted my exe to his desktop and it worked fine. I'm wondering if the shared folder is more dangerous for the exe program to validate, this is beyond my knowledge, have you had similar problems?

Comment: That adds some light to it. An exe file that is located directly on a shared folder is treated by Windows like a file downloaded from the internet (it gets a [special mark](https://www.howtogeek.com/70012/what-causes-the-file-downloaded-from-the-internet-warning-and-how-can-i-easily-remove-it/)). Depending on the system settings, such files may be blocked if they are unsigned. When you zip the exe file, only the zip file gets this mark, so the exe file extracted from the zip won't have it.